# Is there a way to determine whether a specific point on the secp256k1 curve is a valid Bitcoin public key?

Tags: secp256k1

Let's first define a `valid Bitcoin private key` as a number in the range of [1, 115792089237316195423570985008687907852837564279074904382605163141518161494336], and a `valid Bitcoin public key` as a public key derived from a valid Bitcoin private key.

Then my question is: Is there a way to determine whether a specific point on the secp256k1 curve is a valid Bitcoin public key?

Answer (score 3):

The secp256k1 curve has cofactor one, so every point on the curve can be written as a multiple of the generator. As a result, there are exactly as many points on the curve (excluding the point at infinity) as there are valid (nonzero) private keys.

In short: yes, every point on the curve is a valid public key.

Comment: The point K = (9166C289B9F905E55F9E3DF9F69D7F356B4A22095F894F4715714AA4B56606AF, F181EB966BE4ACB5CFF9E16B66D809BE94E214F06C93FD091099AF98499255E7) is part of the secp256k1 curve, but it's derived from an invalid private key (FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF), such that according to the definition in my question, the point is not a valid Bitcoin public key. Question that remains: is there a non-brute-force way to determine such validity of a public key?

Comment: @drogos86 That point also has corresponding (valid) private key 0x000000000000000000000000000000014551231950b75fc4402da1732fc9bebe. The restriction for private keys to be in range 1 to 0xfffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffebaaedce6af48a03bbfd25e8cd0364141 is simply to make sure there is exactly one private key for every public key, but beyond that, private keys act "modulo" the size of the curve.